# Script a needs data from script b, but script b also needs data from script a. Can I import two-way?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I'm currently working on a script, `script1.py`, which uses a class defined in `script2.py`. However, that class in `script2.py` uses an instance of another class defined in `script1.py`, so essentially both scripts need to import variables from one another to make the entirity work. I can't get this to work and though I can import one-way, I can't manage to import two-way (so both scripts recognize the desired data from the other script). What would be the most logical workaround for this?